# Split DateTime string in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, split

I have a Datetime string with unknown format, and I would like to split it to 2 different variables of Date & Time but keep the same format.

The format can contain several spaces so I can't split the string by spaces (for example: "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS T").

How can I do it?

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: Can you post something you have tried, what you exactly want to know?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a starting idea, but as @RobG noticed (in comment) is format dependent:

```
datetime = new Date(dateTimeInString);
day = datetime.getDate();
month = datetime.getMonth() + 1; //month: 0-11
year = datetime.getFullYear();
date = year + "-" + day + "-" + month;
hours = datetime.getHours();
minutes = datetime.getMinutes();
seconds = datetime.getSeconds();
time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

Comment: So basically toss it at the Date constructor whose [*parser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) is implementation dependent and might return anything? You'll only know if it went wrong if the result is NaN, and even then not know why. E.g. `'2014-10-12T12:30:30'` will return different results (i.e. Date objects for different moments) in current browsers and NaN in most older ones. Oh, and *getDate* returns just the day in the month, not the full day, month and year.

Comment: You're right. I understand, my solution is not the best one.
How could we improve it?